# Create cmd shortcut to open directory and automatically run Angular command ng serve

Tags: windows, cmd, command, angular-cli, shortcut

I want to have a shortcut on my desktop that opens `cmd`, navigates to my `Angular directory` and runs the command `ng serve -o`

Adding this to a shortcut will open the right directory:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k " cd\ & cd "C:\MyAngularDirectory\"
```

However when I add another (Angular cli) command it does not execute automatically. This does not work for example:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k " cd\ & cd "C:\MyAngularDirectory\" & ng serve -o
```

I have tried creating a `bat` file but can't get it to work.

Comment: Well I would advise that you do not create a shortcut with either of those attempts. Please take a look at the properties of any shortcut on your system, and look the the fields. Among them, the `Start in:` should define the current directory. So your actual command line should not need to separately change that working directory, and should not therefore be included / needed. Your 'Start in:' should be `"C:\MyAngularDirectory"` and you would not need `cd\ & cd "C:\MyAngularDirectory\"`.

Comment: Thank you, that works! These commands and arguments are like regex to me.

Comment: @Compo it automatically adjusts the field 'start in' to C:\Windows\System32